# How to hide a div after 3 clicks in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an input tag inside a div tag. I need to hide the div tag after clicking three times in the input tag. How do I achieve this in HTML using angular?

Comment: create a counter that counts the number of clicks and set the element's CSS property to hidden after the condition is met

Comment: can you please add an example if you have one?

Comment: Try to avoid these kind of questions, to ask some doubt on StackOverflow, at least, research for your problem and describe your effort until now. Posting this kind of question, it seems like you didn't had any own effort to solve your problem and wants explictly that someone make all the job for you.

Comment: This is what I've tried till now,  <div>
            <input id="abc"  (click)="clickMe()"/>
        </div>         clickMe() {
        this.clickCount+= 1;
        document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = this.clickCount;

    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have endless solutions for this but, the idea would be that you have a counter that start at 0, after each click you increment it and when it reaches 3 you change the class/style applied to the div parent.

I have created a stackblitz app as an example for you, hope it helps:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/hide-element-after-3-clicks?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am new to stackoverflow and was trying on how to post a question properly. This is the solution I wanted.